# Virustotal detecting threats in Suricata rule set

Tags: virus, antivirus, scan, suricata

Virustotal scans are detecting threats from the Suricata default rule pack located https://rules.emergingthreats.net/open/suricata-4.0/

Is this a false positive?
https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/c20b744a3ca4d8fef3fa23633db7e94edd064d5ea149be0a4ce063a85046b76f/detection
https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/bad1ab778b89d4f8a0a42d0df8b09e37d9ba0e2cffb6169b423e63f9a9fdcafa/detection

Comment: It would make sense. As the signature is contained in the package and the AV might detect the signature. Not sure tho...

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that the rule sets are plain files that contains rules for snort/suricata I would consider has a false positive, I just download the .tar.gz and there is nothing suspicious there, just the regular files from the set, on the other hand, it could be a fake set and not the official one, better to ask on the mailing list and see the responses if you have doubts about it

```
[camp0@localhost Downloads]$ sha256sum emerging.rules.tar.gz 
c20b744a3ca4d8fef3fa23633db7e94edd064d5ea149be0a4ce063a85046b76f   emerging.rules.tar.gz
```

Download the same file as virustotal report but nothing interesting inside.